# prevent tomcat 7 from deleting my custom context file on every single overwrite/undeploy of my webapp

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat7, datasource

I have a web application deployed on tomcat 7. Its context file, named myAppName.xml is located in
`$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost folder.`

The problem I'm facing is that on each overwrite or undeploy, my configuration file is deleted from `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost` folder and I have to copy/paste it from a backup location.

How can I prevent this behavior?  I don't want to copy/paste context file everytime I change something in webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it into web/META-INF in the source tree, then Tomcat will copy it out of there into conf/.... on each deploy. Tomcat 7 won't even do that by default, just use it where it is.

Comment: But what happens when I want to keep my configuration outside of my war file?
I want to be able to deploy the same war file on several server with different configuration.

Comment: So do exactly that. Deploy it separately from the WAR file. Just don't keep it in a place where To cat will clobber it, or expect Tomcat to preserve it across WAR reloads.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand where do you suggest to put the context file. What do you mean by "web/META-INF in the source tree"?
This issue happens typically when you update .war file (the idea here is to have/keep configuration OUTSIDE of the .war). In this case you have to maintain a copy of your context file elsewhere because Tomcat will remove it by doing a two steps update: undeploy, deploy.

Comment: @Destroyica 'web/META-INF in the source tree' seems clear to me, and so does 'separately from the WAR file'. They're two different recommendations, not the same one, if that's what's confusing you.

Comment: what is "the source tree" ?

Comment: @VinyJones The directory structure containing your source files.

Comment: If the context.xml is inside the META-INF directory in the source project, then it will be packed into the war file and deployed with it. Which is exactly not what OP wants.
In my project, the META-INF/context.xml contains default configuration, that needs to be adapted to production/dev/whatever. The production config needs to stay intact on the server even if app is redeployed.

Comment: @Katharsas That's exactly what this answer already says. Your point? You appear to be talking about the opposite scenario from the OP's.

Comment: Hm, could be i meant Destroyicas use case. Anyway the problem i'm speaking about probably belongs to a different question.